# Google App Maker Total field

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a filtered list as shown on the screenshot below

[screenshot of the filtered list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z34dN.png)

I would like to calculate to total of "Km" in a separate field.

Can you help me ?

Here is the screen shot with the structure of the widget :

[Structure Admin View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z34dN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following will work:

```
TableListWidget.children._values
  .map(function(obj){ 
    return parseInt(obj.descendants.nameOfYourKMField.value);
  })
  .reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue){ 
    return accumulator + currentValue; 
  });
```

`TableListWidget.children._vaues` contains an array of all your table rows, the `descendants` property of each row will contain the widget which has your KM value.  We map the `_values` array to an array of KM field values and then use the `reduce` function to add them.

Comment: Thanks, 

I don't know what to replace "TableListWidget". I have tried Table1Panel
Table1
Table1Body
Table1Row
Without success.

Comment: You need to replace `TableListWidget` with whatever the table's list widget is.  You'll also need to replace `nameOfYourKMField`.  So if you want some label to display the total number of KM you'll need to switch that label's onDataLoad event and have `TableListWidget` be `widget.root.descendants.Table1Body`.

Comment: Just noticed you attached the structure of your page.  In this case if you wanted to have some label display the total you would use the following for your onDataLoad event:



`widget.text = widget.root.descendants.Table1Body.children._values.map(function(obj){ return parseInt(obj.descendants.Field1.value); }).reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue){ return accumulator + currentValue; }).toString();`

Comment: Just did it. Sorry, I did'nt know how to do it before. :-) Thank you again

Comment: does this also cater decimal value eg: 10.99